# Is there a way to compare a timestamp against the last two days?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Here is my timestamp, I would like to return a boolean if possible.

`2016-01-19T00:00:00.000Z`

I am preferably looking for a simple vanilla javascript answer.

Comment: You're sure it's not `2016-01-19T00:00:00.000Z`

Comment: `(new Date().getTime() - new Date("2016-01-19T00:00:00.000Z").getTime()) / 1000 / 60 / 60 / 24 < 2` something like that?  BTW, what adeneo is getting at is that "2016-1-19T00:00:00.000Z" is an invalid date format.

Comment: Yeah my bad, I forgot to add the zero. @adeneo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
function daysPassed(date){
    return Math.round((new Date() - date)/ (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
}

var date = new Date("2016-01-19T00:00:00.000Z"); 

if(daysPassed(date) <= 2){
    //two days or less -- do something
}
```

Comment: Thanks Marcos Casagrande that's exactly what I was looking for!